# Как задать setFixedSize для Texture View

Tags: java, android, kotlin, webrtc

В SurfaceView есть метод setFixedSize, чтобы фиксированно установить размер отображаемого видео. Как установить такой же фиксированный размер для TextureView?

Answer (score 0):

Возможно здесь есть ответ на ваш вопрос https://github.com/warnyul/fast-video-view/blob/1ff67453c632f0da0c7e8657ed8d67167d892811/video/src/main/java/com/warnyul/android/widget/FastVideoView.java#L324

Comment: [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)